# Date Validation, Input[date] & Datepicker on AngularJS for Firefox

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a compatability issue with Firefox. I already have a working Angular app for production, but the date input only works on Chrome. I had overlooked this and now I have a broken app when it runs in Firefox and IE.

I do not want to go over the AngularJS-Bootstrap Datepicker route because:

1. I already have a structured app which is working on webkit browsers.
2. My app is a separate AngularJS (stand-alone) from my Bootstrap-Compass under a single app.
3. I didn't use Angular-Bootstrap as I was not aware that there exists.
4. I only have a small conundrum which is the input[date], which is a
   mere HTML5 compatability issue with other browsers.
5. Since it's just a small issue, I do not want to make a major
   workaround just for it.
6. I only have limited time to fix this, so I must resolve it ASAP.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I tried the AngularJS-Bootstrap UI, but it depends on version 1.2,
   and I'm running AngularJS 1.3
2. The directive to make it work on Firefox seems too much of a tweak or at least it lacks detailed info to do so.
3. I am currently trying to use jQuery UI's datepicker, but for some reason, it does not work within the app (it works outside the app though).

Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" id="bdate" name="bdate" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.bdate.$invalid}" ng-model="formData.bdate" required class="form-control" placeholder="Birthday mm/dd/yyyy">
```

It has a validation like this:

```
<li ng-show="signup.bdate.$error.date"><p>Please enter a valid birth date.</p></li>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var spinnrApp = angular.module('spinnrApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'slick', 'ngMessages']);

spinnrApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('registration', {
      url: "/registration",
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/registration.php",
      controller: "FormController"
    })
    .state('registration.spinnrapp', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/spinnrapp", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-profile.php"
    })
    .state('registration.artist', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/artist", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-artist.php"
    })
    .state('registration.share', { // each nested state will have their own view
      url: "/share", // url will be nested /registration/share
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-share.php"
    });
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/registration/spinnrapp");
});

spinnrApp.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function (scope, http, state){

  // get list of cities and store it to select
  http.get('cities.json').success(function(data){
    scope.cities = data;
  })

  // we will store all our form data in this object
  scope.formData = {};

  // function to process the form
  scope.processForm = function(isValid) {
    scope.$submitted = true;
    if(isValid && state.$current=='registration.spinnrapp') {
      state.go('registration.artist');
    } else if(isValid && state.$current=='registration.artist') {
      state.go('registration.share');
    } else if(!isValid && state.$current=='registration.artist') {
      alert('Please make sure you have selected an artist.');
    }
  };
}]);
```

Here are my main questions:

1. If I'm going to use a directive, how do I do that based on this
   current structure?
2. Why is it that the jQuery datepicker fails to run when its within the Angular app but runs perfectly when I take it outside as a static DOM element?
3. Is there a simple approach I can do here so I won't have to resort to a lot of code tweaking?

Lastly, here are all my scripts in case you are wondering how I put this all together (index.php):

```
<script src="app/angular/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
<script src="app/angular/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/angular/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/angular/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/angular/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/angular/angular-slick/dist/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bdate").datepicker();
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var target = this.href.split('#');
      $('.nav a').filter('[href="#'+target[1]+'"]').tab('show');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input id is "bdate" change $("#datepicker").datepicker(); to $("#bdate").datepicker();

Comment: I edited this now. This is not the issue here though.